# Sorry , We Can't Connect to the sharepoint store

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

[image]

I need Help about this issue , i have four day trying to fix the problem.
Note: I have the catalog app, the DNS and the necessary subscriptions that SharePoint in the Central Administration Portal on SharePoint.

I wait your comments .

Comment: is it foundation or enterprise/standard edtion.  is internet working from the server which you are trying ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below.

- Make Sure the [Root Certificate Added into trusted Root Chain.](http://sharepoint-sezai-moss-2007.blogspot.com/2012/12/sharepoint-server-2013-rtm-apps-sorry.html)
- Make Sure the  [internet access to the Store feature ACTIVATED](http://blogs.technet.com/b/lukeb/archive/2013/05/09/sharepoint-microsoft-sharepoint-store.aspx)
- Make sure your app domain works fine.
- Make sure App Management Service and Microsoft SharePoint Foundation
  Subscription Settings Service is started on your server.
- Make sure App Management Service Application and Microsoft SharePoint
  Foundation Subscription Settings Service Application is started.
- Check the detail error message of ULS log  to determine the exact
  cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft help had me do the following to resolved the issue.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-support-in-sharepoint-server-2016#enablestrongcrypto4.5

Answer (score 0):

Adding the reg key net46-strong-crypto-enable.reg with

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
```

and then a reboot fixed it for me